# Libgdx Linux Issue

Tags: java, linux, libgdx

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and when I tried to run a DesktopLauncher of Libgdx generated project, I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setVSync(LwjglGraphics.java:503)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:118)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.getAvailableDisplayModes(LinuxDisplay.java:954)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.init(LinuxDisplay.java:738)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:138)
    ... 2 more
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

I know that there is a "solving" to this problem (http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=18801) but it doesn't work. Can someone tell me how can I fix this?

Comment: If you are using a dockingstation you need to reboot after docking in/out. I am having the same issue. Of course this is more a work around than a solution..

Comment: I still can't run project...

Comment: Now it throws `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/jnigen/NativeCodeGenerator
 at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild.main(GdxBuild.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.NativeCodeGenerator
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 1 more`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I installed nvidia video driver and project started working.